ADO API for 'Suite Test Case - Update' doesn't work if we want the 'isActive' to be set as true
https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_apis/testplan/Plans/2781987/Suites/4930403/TestPoint?api-version=7.1-preview.2
For the above link, when I used the Request Payload as
[ { "id": 2218725, "results": { "outcome": "passed" }, "tester": { "displayName": "xxxxx", "url": "xxxxx", "_links": { "avatar": { "href": "xxxxx" } }, "id": "xxxxx", "uniqueName": "xxxxx", "imageUrl": "xxxxx", "descriptor": "xxxxx" } } ]
This updates the isActive state from 'true' to 'false'
But I'm unable to update the isActive state from 'false' to 'true'.
I tried changing the request payload but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions ?

The mentioned rest api Test Point - Update works fine for me. You can simplify the body.  Please check the powershell script sample:
# Define parameters
$organization = ""
$project = ""
$planId = "110"    # test plan id
$suiteId = "253"   # test suite id

# Personal Access Token (PAT)
$personalToken = ""


$token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}


$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/testplan/Plans/$planId/Suites/$suiteId/TestPoint?api-version=7.1-preview.2"


Write-Host "Check the uri Value:"
Write-Host $uri


# Define the body, replace testpoint id with yours.
$body = @"
[{`"id`":20,`"isActive`":true}]
"@

# Call the REST API
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"

# Output the response
Write-Host "Check the isActive Value:"

$response.value.isActive




Thank you for the quick response. This solution works for me !

You are welcome. Glad to know it works. Happy day!
